# Child process unable to read from created pseudo terminal

Tags: c, posix, pty

I'm trying to write an app that can login to SSH with a password, by using pseudo terminals. But if I write() to the master device then the data somehow does not appear in the slave device. Here's a simple test case:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#ifdef __linux__
    #include <pty.h>
#else
    #include <util.h>
#endif

int
main() {
    int master;
    pid_t pid = forkpty(&master, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (pid == 0) {
        int ch;
        read(0, &ch, 1);
        _exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("Press Enter to send a byte.\n");
        getchar();
        write(master, "1", 1);
        printf("Done. Waiting for process to exit...\n");
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The app will first output "Press Enter to send a byte". After pressing Enter, I expect the child process's read() to return. But the read() there seems to block indefinitely even though the master's write() succeeds, so the master waits forever on the waitpid(). What's going on?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using this for, but I would use `expect` for something like this.  It's available on most distributions.  http://expect.nist.gov/

Comment: The app that I'm writing is going to be distributed to users who may not have 'expect' or and may not want to install it. Besides I also want to know how to do pseudo terminals right in case I need them for anything else in the future.

Comment: try this:  write(master, "1\n", 2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't modify the line discipline of the PTY.  The default line discipline is line oriented, so no input will be sent to the slave process until a newline character is read.  (You can see this by sending a "\n" to the slave, instead of just "1".)  You can run the PTY in RAW mode by, in the child process, calling `tcgetattr`, `cfmakeraw` and `tcsetattr`, like follows:

```
    if (pid == 0) {
        int ch;
        struct termios t;
        tcgetattr(0, &t);
        cfmakeraw(&t);
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t);
        read(0, &ch, 1);
        _exit(1);
    } else {
```

This seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The example code at [this blog post](http://rmathew.blogspot.com/2006/09/terminal-sickness.html) should probably be of help. The author has an update  to his original problem (very similar to yours) with a usable `spawn (char *argv[]);` function given.